# Why does this task exit without delay?

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library, .net-4.5

I have been using System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run() all over the place with great success.  I discovered recently that one of my processes exits prematurely because a Task does not complete.  Apparently, I haven't the first clue how System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run() actually works and my 100,000+ lines of C# code (three windows services, web application, database and in-memory inter-process cache) works by sheer luck.  Here is a simplified version of the code.  Why does the process exit without executing the delay?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TaskWaitDemo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Task.Delay(60 * 1000).Wait();
                        // In my actual code I perform real computation right here after the wait.
                        Console.WriteLine("why does this line never execute???");
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Trying to embrace the Thread-agnostic world of Tasks, I am using Tasks to two primary purposes: 1) to queue up work to the thread pool, and 2) to handle periodic tasks asynchronously.  My example above was an overly simplified attempt to show an example of a periodic task.  IN my real application the `While (true) { ... }` is actually more like a `while (!_shutdown) { ... }`.

The various comments and answers all suggest simply Waiting on the Task, but in my real application the main Thread may or may not have things to do after starting a Task and cannot simply Wait on my periodic Tasks without blocking forever.

In the olden days of Threads, Thread A would start Thread B, and then might gracefully exit if it had nothing left to do, leaving Thread B merrily doing its thing and the process still running.

It seems that, in the brave new world of Tasks, Thread A runs Task B (to queue up some work, possibly periodic, to the thread pool), and then might gracefully exit if it has nothing left to do.  The framework then tosses Task B (and apparently any other work queued to the thread pool via Tasks) into the bit bucket and the process terminates.  Seems broken to me.

I guess my answer is to use good old Threads for periodic tasks, and hope and pray that all my fire-and-forget Tasks on the thread pool queue are complete before allowing the application to shutdown.

Comment: Your `Main` creates a task but doesn't wait it to finish. use Wait.

Comment: You aren't waiting for the Task you create with `Task.Run` to finish.

Comment: Calling Wait on the Task returned by Task.Run() is exactly what I don't want to do.  The whole point of Task.Run() is to queue work to the thread pool and NOT wait for it.

Comment: @AngCaruso then use `Console.ReadLine()` :)

Comment: @AngCaruso So, you want to wait for the thread to finish working before exiting the application... but without waiting for it?

Comment: @Lilshieste I want the framework to guarantee that all the work I have queued to the thread pool via `Task.Run()` is complete (on any or all Threads in the pool, I don't care which) before the application exits, without having to explicitly `Wait()` for it OR explicitly keep a Thread alive.  I thought the point of the TPL was to eliminate the need to explicitly manage Threads.  Forcing me to explicitly `Wait()` OR keep a Thread alive is still forcing me to manage Threads in my opinion.

Comment: @AngCaruso The point of the TPL isn't to eliminate the need to explicitly manage threads - the point is to *simplify* that management. I understand your frustration, but how would you expect the framework to provide the guarantee that you're looking for? The framework would have to shoehorn a *hidden* `Wait()` at the end of your application - but most people wouldn't want that to happen. Consider a daemon thread that operated in a `while(true)` loop: if the framework forced the application to wait for it to "complete", the application would hang.

Answer (score 4):

you run `while(true)`, yes that is correct, but you run that on **another thread**.

Main thread, instead, runs all through the `Main` and exits the app.

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            //MAIN THREAD BOUNDS
            //LAUNCH THE TASK AND GO AHEAD
            var task = Task.Run(() => (EDIT)
            {    
                //SECOND THREAD BOUNDS 
                while (true)
                {
                  ...
                }
               //--------------
            });
            task.Wait(); (EDIT) //WAIT FOR TASK COMPLETION  !!!!

            //NOTHING MORE TO DO, SO EXIT APP AND KILL Task.Run THREAD
        }
```

**EDIT**

if you need to wait for the completion just use [Task.Wait](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd235606(v=vs.110).aspx), like in edited code. In this concrete example it makes no sence, which does not necessary mean it will not in *yours*.

Comment: But there is something more to do, and that is to complete the Delay() in the second thread and then execute the code that follows it (and then execute the next loop iteration, ad infinitum).  Why is the second thread a second class citizen?

Comment: And the way you say that with Tasks is for Main to Wait until that work is done. Forget thread-think, you need task-think.

Answer (score 0):

A better structure for your task would be:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var task = new Task(() => 
    {         
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Computing..");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    });
    task.Start();
    task.Wait(); //Wait for the task to finish
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using the task constructor here, the OP was correct in his use of `Task.Run`.